# How to link mysql-client installed from Homebrew with diesel-cli?

Tags: mysql, macos, rust, linker-errors, rust-diesel

I have been trying to install the Rust Diesel CLI tool using `cargo install diesel_cli`, but the installation fails with a linking error

```
ld: library not found for -lmysqlclient
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 
(use -v to see invocation)
```

I installed the MySQL client using Homebrew: `brew install mysql-client`. During installation I got the following warning:

```
mysql-client is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because conflicts with mysql.
If you need to have mysql-client first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql-client/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
For compilers to find mysql-client you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/mysql-client/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/mysql-client/include”
```

I set the `PATH` and flags as in that warning message, but I still get the above linking error when trying to install the diesel-cli tool. I am  unfamiliar with how to do linking in Rust - are there extra steps I need to do here to link mysqlclient directly?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Cargo ignores `LDFLAGS` and `CPPFLAGS`, you should set `RUSTFLAGS` instead. Something like this untested invocation:

```
RUSTFLAGS="-L/your_lib -I/your_include" cargo install diesel_cli
```

[Relevant documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html#environment-variables-cargo-reads).

Comment: Thank you, that's really helpful! Running 
```RUSTFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/mysql-client/lib" cargo install diesel_cli``` did the trick

Comment: Passing `-I` gives me `error: Unrecognized option: 'I'` (rustc/cargo 1.40.0), but passing `-L` suffices to make it build.

Comment: I've installed `mysql-client` using homebrew and then tried `RUSTFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql-client/lib" cargo install diesel_cli --no-default-features --features "mysql"` - worked just fine!

Answer (score 3):

On my side, I did not make it work with a mysql-client only. I had to install mysql with

```
brew install mysql
```

In the end, what matters is that you have a version of the mysqlclient dynamic lib.

Mines where installed here :

```
/usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.15/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib
```

And it worked.